# How do I translate a point from one rect to a point in a scaled rect?

Tags: graphics, scaling

I have an image (i) that's been scaled from its original size (rectLarge) to fit a smaller rectangle (rectSmall).  Given a point p in rectSmall, how can I translate this to a point in rectLarge.

To make this concrete, suppose I have a 20x20 image that's been scaled to a 10x10 rect.  The point (1, 1) in the smaller rect should be scaled up to a point in the larger rect (i.e. (2,2)).

I'm trying to achieve this with:

```
result.x = point.x * (destRect.size.width / srcRect.size.width );
result.y = point.y * (destRect.size.height / srcRect.size.height);
```

However, the points generated by this code are not correct - they do not map to the appropriate point in the original image.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In what way are those points not positioned correctly? Bear in mind that sometimes scaling to other values than multiplies of largest common denominator can produce noninteger values in the division and than some sort of rounding occours.

Comment: Gabriel, I gave some additional explanation in response to Jacob's answer below.

Comment: Can you give some examples of the sizes that are giving incorrect results?  destRect.size, srcRect.size, point, and result, so we can better help debug it?

Answer (score 1):

What language are you using?

If this is C, and `rect.size.height` and the like are ints, then you have a major rounding problem.  Say you're scaling point `10, 10` from a size `20x20` back up to a size `30x30`.  Your calculations will look like:

```
result.x = 10 * (30 / 20);
```

This simplifies to:

```
result.x = 10 * (1);
```

The simplest way to fix this is to get rid of the parentheses:

```
result.x = point.x * destRect.size.width / srcRect.size.width;
result.y = point.y * destRect.size.height / srcRect.size.height;
```

Now your calculation, `10 * 30 / 20`, simplifies to `300 / 20` and then to `15`, which is what you want.

Note, you still have a slight rounding problem, but unless you can get subpixel locations, this is about as close as you're gonna get.

Comment: Objective-C, so C arithmetic rules apply.  These values are all floats.

Answer (score 0):

What is the "appropriate point"? If the size of `srcRect` is larger than `destRect` then your code is correct. Also, don't forget that `result.x` and `result.y` will be a floating point number and to use them in the image you need to round it or do bilinear interpolation, etc. Before, I can give a more detailed answer, what are you going to do with `result`?

Comment: To elaborate a little, I have an image which is slightly larger than the available screen.  The image is scaled down slightly for a "Preview" mode where the user clicks a point to indicate a region.

I need to translate that point from the preview image's rectangle to the original image in order to process the region.

srcRect is larger than destRect.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is that your rectangle is positioned not at `(0, 0)` and, therefore, you can't scale every point inside it the same way as you scale it's dimensions.

You will have to determine the offset from some anchor point in your rectangle (for example, top left point), then your resulting point would be `anchor_point.x + offset.x * (horizontal_scale_ratio)` and the same for `y` (with `vertical_scale_ratio`).

Ratios there are `new_width / old_width` and `new_height / old_height`.

Comment: (point.x, point.y) is relative to the top-left of the smaller rectangle.

Comment: Then I think your problem is either in another place or smth like that. The chunk of code you've posted seems good and I don't suspect any problems in it.